# Find Path to the First Occurrence in a Nested Data Structure

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, clojurescript, tail-recursion

Consider the following numbers nested by vectors in a tree-structure

```
(def tree [7 9 [7 5 3 [4 6 9] 9 3] 1 [2 7 9 9]])
```

My goal is to find the path to the first even number that can be found by traversing the tree: In the upper example this would be 4, the path from the root to this node would be [2 3 0]

```
(def result [2 3 0])
```

I got some difficulties writing a function tho archive this. However, the following function finds the first even number, not its path:

```
(defn find-even [x]
  (if (vector? x)
    (some #(when-let [subresult (find-even %)]
             (when (even? subresult)
               subresult)) x)
    x))

(find-even tree) ;; 4
```

What would I have to do in order to receive the path to the result?

---

**EDIT**

I figured out a way to do it. Here is a function that - at least - works:

```
(defn find-even-path [x]
  (letfn [(traverse [x]
            (if (vector? x)
              (some (fn [[i v]] (when-let [subresult (traverse v)]
                                  (when (even? (:value subresult))
                                    (update subresult :path conj i))))
                    (map-indexed vector x))
              {:path '()
               :value x}))]
    (when-let [result (traverse x)]
      (vec (:path result)))))

(find-even-path tree) ;; [2 3 0]
```

However, I'd still be curious to hear what could be optimized here. It still looks quite complex to me and is not tail recursive yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it tail-recursively:

```
(defn tailrec-depth-first-path [is? tree]
  (loop [[tree i path fk] [tree 0 [] nil]]
    (cond
      (>= i (count tree))
        (if (nil? fk) nil (recur fk))
      (vector? (tree i))
        (recur [(tree i) 0 (conj path i) [tree (inc i) path fk]])
      (is? (tree i))
        (conj path i)
      :else
        (recur [tree (inc i) path fk]))))

(tailrec-depth-first-path even? [7 9 [7 5 3 [4 6 9] 9 3] 1 [2 7 9 9]])
=> [2 3 0]
```

The function adds one more index to `path` each time it descends further down the tree. The main trick of note here is the use of a "failure continuation", represented by the variable `fk`. `fk` is the next set of arguments to pass to `loop` to continue the search after a failed search of a subtree, or nil if the search is at the top level. This enables backtracking without violating tail-recursion. In other words, the information that, in a non-tail-recursive version, would be needed to do the work remaining after the recursive call, is accumulated in `fk` in the tail-recursive version.

---

A quick test on my 2009 MacBook Air (1.86 GHz Core 2 Duo) suggests that the tail-recursive version is the fastest of the answers posted so far:

```
(def tree [7 9 [7 5 3 [4 6 9] 9 3] 1 [2 7 9 9]])

(time (dotimes [_ 100000] (find-even-path tree)))
"Elapsed time: 1153.137475 msecs"

(time (dotimes [_ 100000] (first (findt tree even? []))))
"Elapsed time: 1413.502082 msecs"

(time (dotimes [_ 100000] (depth-first-path even? tree)))
"Elapsed time: 690.56115 msecs"

(time (dotimes [_ 100000] (tailrec-depth-first-path even? tree)))
"Elapsed time: 524.332278 msecs"
```

Comment: great! Just one thing: findt searches lazily for all results in the tree. In order to make your testing fair you should wrap it with a (first ..)

Comment: @AntonHarald Thanks! Good point. I just fixed it. Amazingly, realizing the first element of the lazy vector took an additional 300 ms. (It's possible to shave off about 10–20 ms by passing `findt` an empty list in its last argument instead of an empty vector, since `cons` is slow on vectors.)

Comment: Interesting. How can that be explained? The only thing, that comes to my mind is: "Many of the lazy sequence functions in Clojure amortize the realization of elements by producing a “chunk” of N elements at a time" (http://insideclojure.org/2015/01/02/sequences/) This would mean that the advantage of the laziness only shows up at 'sequences' larger than N. If the lazy operations on our test tree are fewer than N, the whole thing has to be evaluated anyways and then calling `first` on the result would cause the additional ms. But this is just guessing.

Comment: @AntonHarald My understanding is that laziness always costs performance. The reason is that there's extra book-keeping and complexity involved to handle laziness. Laziness _appears_ to pay off only when you don't look at the postponed values. Even then, lazily evaluating things that you never look at is slower than not evaluating them at all. The only advantage of laziness is that it's sometimes very convenient to the programmer to express things lazily; it's always worse for the CPU (unless the compiler is _very_ clever).

Comment: @AntonHarald I think I just figured out why realizing the first item from `findt` is so slow. If you change the `mapcat` to `map`, `findt` returns `(nil nil (nil nil nil ([(2 3 0)] [(2 3 1)] nil) nil nil) nil ([(4 0)] nil nil nil))`. So, to get the first item, it has to generate, examine, and reject five nils. The non-lazy version doesn't generate any of that extra stuff.

Comment: Now I had time to check that again. It turned out that my assumption about the chunks was not right. I think, (first (findt ...)) was slower than (findt ...) because the later was not evaluated at all. It would have to be wrapped in a `doall` - `first` does this implicitly. You know, `(take 1)` for instance doesn't evaluate as well, it just produces another lazy sequence.

Comment: I modified the function you proposed for another purpose and got some issues with that. In case you are interested, a post with this is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36829660/iteratively-construct-trie-from-a-tree).

Comment: @AntonHarald BTW, I think chunking explains more about why `(first (findt …))` runs so slowly: `mapcat` realized the entire seq of paths even though only the first one was ever used. (If there were many paths, it would have stopped after realizing the first 32, of course.)

Comment: Things turn out to be quite confusing here. What brings some light to the discussion is putting a `(prn "x")` side effect just to the first line of the function passed to `mapcat`. The amount of printed `x`'s obviously indicates the number of times this part has actually been called. Playing around with this, three things can be observed: (1) chunking seems only to happen if there are no infinite sequences involved. (2) `time` times only the items that are actually requested, some x's are printed behind the timing result. (3) The later suggest that `findt` might not be fully lazy.

Comment: However `mapcat` seems to have a chunking behavior which I cannot grasp. It behaves differently than `(concat (map ..))`. However the `doc` of `mapcat` says it should.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option. The idea is to keep a "stacktrace" of indices while traversing the list (the `r` argument). Every time we find an item that satisfies the `p` predicate, we return that "stacktrace". If none was found, we simply return nil. `mapcat` concatenates all the non-empty (non-nil) lists into one resulting list:

```
(defn findt [t p r]
  (mapcat (fn[i c]
            (if (coll? c)
              (findt c p (cons i r))
              (when (p c) [(reverse (cons i r))]))) (range) t))
```

Its still not tail recursive, but it can find all paths (lazily, due to the use of `mapcat`):

```
(def tree [7 9 [7 5 3 [4 6 9] 9 3] 1 [2 7 9 9]])

(findt tree even? [])
=> ((2 3 0) (2 3 1) (4 0))
```

And we can test it with:

```
(->> (findt tree odd? [])
 (map #(get-in tree %))
 (every? odd?))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll look at it more closely soon. I just discovered that the solution I proposed has a bug. It doesn't work for [[1 1 1] 2]. Have to fix that first.

Comment: Alright, makes sense to me now. I suppose that your function is lazy - since I need only the first occurrence. This could be done with 'first' then. If you could update your answer considering this would be great!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't tail-recursive, but it's straightforward:

```
(defn depth-first-path 
 ([is? tree]
  (depth-first-path is? tree []))
 ([is? tree path-so-far]
  (cond
    (vector? tree)
      (some identity (map #(depth-first-path is? %1 (conj path-so-far %2))
                          tree
                          (range)))
    (is? tree)
      path-so-far
    :else
      nil)))

(depth-first-path even? [7 9 [7 5 3 [4 6 9] 9 3] 1 [2 7 9 9]])
=> [2 3 0]
```

I called it `depth-first-path` because there are other reasonable ways to define "first" when searching a tree.

Note: I'm new to Clojure, and I haven't even looked at [clojure.walk](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.walk) or [Specter](https://github.com/nathanmarz/specter). There is probably an easier way.