# Iteratively Construct Trie from a Tree

Tags: clojure, tree, iteration, clojurescript, trie

**Introduction**

The following function iteratively traverses a tree structure made of nested vectors. It tests each leaf against a predicate. The paths to all leaves which pass that truth-test are returned in a [Trie structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). The later describes all found paths in a non-redundant way.

```
(defn get-trie-of-matches [is? tree]
  (loop [[tree i path fk] [tree 0 [] nil]
         accum {}]
    (cond
      (>= i (count tree)) ;; end of level / go up
      (if (nil? fk) accum (recur fk accum))

      (vector? (tree i)) ;; level down
      (recur [(tree i) 0 (conj path i) [tree (inc i) path fk]] accum)

      (is? (tree i)) ;; match
      (let [new-accum (assoc-in accum (conj path i) {})]
        (recur [tree (inc i) path fk] new-accum))

      :else ;; next on same level
      (recur [tree (inc i) path fk] accum))))
```

For further explanations see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36808383/find-path-to-the-first-occurrence-in-a-nested-data-structure).

**Example**

Consider the following tree

```
(def tree [7 9 [7 5 3 [4 6 9] 9 3] 1 [2 7 9 9]])
```

Applied to the function, using `even?` as a predicate:

```
(get-trie-of-matches even? tree)
=> {2 {3 {0 {}, 1 {}}}, 4 {0 {}}}
```

The result describes the three paths to even numbers in `tree`. Namely `2-3-0`, `2-3-1` and `4-0`.

**Problem**

Even though the above function works, there might be better ways to construct the Trie while traversing the tree. At the moment a hash-map is flooded. On each match via assoc-in. The algorithm traverses the tree structure relatively from level to level but attaches each path in a global fashion to `accum`, which is not necessary. Also this method is only possible since a hashmap is used. It might anyways be better to use a sequential data-structure for the Trie in order to facilitate further iterations over it. This could not be adopted to the above method.

**Question**

How could a Trie be created from within the above function `get-trie-of-matches` without relying on hash-map specific 'global' 'write' functions?

Comment: Have a look at [Specter](http://nathanmarz.com/blog/functional-navigational-programming-in-clojurescript-with-sp.html). It lets you specify how you want to navigate your data structure separately from what you want to put in it. It claims to provide both high performance (better than `get-in` etc.) as well as ease of programming.

Comment: Could you be more specific as to what your issues are with the implementation you give?  There are certainly "better" ways of accomplishing the same thing, but it's not clear what should be different.  For example, what you mean by "hasp-map specific 'global' 'write' functions"?  Are you looking for a lazy solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would propose to take a look at clojure's `walk` api.

It allows you to recursively apply some function to nested collections.
In this case you could use `postwalk`:

```
user> (require '[clojure.walk :as w])
user> (w/postwalk-demo [1 3 [4 [6] 7] [[8]]])
Walked: 1
Walked: 3
Walked: 4
Walked: 6
Walked: [6]
Walked: 7
Walked: [4 [6] 7]
Walked: 8
Walked: [8]
Walked: [[8]]
Walked: [1 3 [4 [6] 7] [[8]]]

[1 3 [4 [6] 7] [[8]]]
```

The key thing is you can replace any item at every step:

```
user> (w/postwalk #(if (coll? %) (reverse %) (inc %))
                  [1 3 [4 [6] 7] [[8]]])

(((9)) (8 (7) 5) 4 2)
```

Here we increment all the numbers, and reverse all the collections, keeping the nested structure.

Now applying to your task:
You could walk through your tree, keeping just even number's indices and not empty collections (e.g. collections containing even numbers, and not empty collections):

```
;; helper function
(defn empty-coll? [item]
  (and (coll? item) (not (seq item))))

(defn make-trie [pred tree]
  (w/postwalk
   #(if (coll? %)
      (keep-indexed (fn [idx item]
                      (cond (empty-coll? item) nil
                            (coll? item) (list idx item)
                            item idx
                            :else nil))
                    %)
      (pred %))
   tree))
```

in repl:

```
user> (def tree [7 9 [7 5 3 [4 6 9] 9 3] 1 [2 7 9 9]])
#'user/tree

user> (make-trie even? tree)
((2 ((3 (0 1)))) (4 (0)))

user> (make-trie #(> % 7) tree)
(1 (2 ((3 (2)) 4)) (4 (2 3)))
```

The structure is similar to your map. In fact you can produce any structure you want with minor changes to the function, for example your map structure:

```
(defn make-trie-map [pred tree]
  (w/postwalk
   #(if (coll? %)
      (into {}
            (keep-indexed (fn [idx item]
                            (cond (empty-coll? item) nil
                                  (coll? item) {idx item}
                                  item {idx {}}
                                  :else nil))
                          %))
      (pred %))
   tree))

user> (make-trie-map even? tree)
{2 {3 {0 {}, 1 {}}}, 4 {0 {}}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very clear, almost tutorial-like introduction to clojure.walk. I see that this would be a reasonable solution to the problem I describe above. However, in my actual usecase, the tree itself is not given beforehand. It is constructed on the base of other data. I want to avoid splitting it up into two steps (building the tree / building the trie), which would mean two full "traversals".

Comment: Hence I think I have to stay with the `loop/recur` code I suggested. My problem with this is still that I cannot merge the trie-data, which was collected on one level, with the data one level higher to this  - if this is explained properly...